# scroll bar problem

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

how to move scroll bar by javascript ,

so that the top coordinate of visible area is y px from top coordinate of entire page?

Answer (score 3):

See the [`window.scrollTo`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_scrollto.asp) and [`window.scrollBy`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_scrollby.asp) methods.

If you need more flexibility and power than that you might try [Flipper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110486/flipper)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894438/scroll-bar-problem/894467#894467) and give the jQuery plugin a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the overhead, use jQuery library with ScrollTo plugin. A quick demo can be found here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/